# Very long login time in Ubuntu Lucid

Tags: boot, ubuntu-10.04, gnome, login

My machine is taking ages to get from the login screen after booting to actually showing the GNOME desktop (as in, over a minute). It seems as though it is just waiting for a long period of that time . This has been a problem for a long time. The [bootchart is available](http://davidf.sjsoft.com/files/bootchart/golg-lucid-20101111-1.png) - any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: do you have home folder encryption enabled?

Comment: No, no encryption

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to a new machine (4-core hyperthreaded instead of dual-core), transferred my OS and home partitions to the new hard drive. No delay on login any more. It seems this laptop was just way too slow.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to ask this in [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) but usually the first thing you do is run `dmesg | less` and see if you find any errors.  If you have already done this and/or some other troubleshooting steps then I apologize for stating the obvious but please share what you found so far.

Comment: AskUbuntu is a good idea: http://askubuntu.com/questions/16505/very-long-gnome-login-time-in-lucid

Comment: I have checked `dmesg` and see no errors - I'd expect that to be more of a problem on initial boot; my slowness seems to happen on login to Gnome

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have login scripts/apps on session startup?

Answer (score 1):

Insert `"*.debug /var/log/debug.log"` to your syslog configuration, and re-examine it for detail information.